# Why function is executed 1 + n times when it should be executed once on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding eventListener like this:

```
var runSingleTest = document.getElementById('runSingleTest');
runSingleTest.addEventListener('click', sendSingeleTestCase);
```

When user click that button in my form following code is executed 1 + n times, where n is number of click on that button before.

```
function sendSingeleTestCase(){
    var frm = $('#scriptCodeForm');
    var btn =  $('#runSingleTest');
    saveScriptToLocalStorage();
    frm.submit(function (ev){
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: btn.attr('formaction'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Test would run once.");
            }
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
    });    
}
```

It doesn't behaves as expected (executed many times when it should be only executed once).

Could you help me to understand possible reasons why it's not working as supposed?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `$('#runSingleTest').one('click', sendSingeleTestCase)`

Comment: If you show your form HTML too I can give an example of the *multiple submit button* problem you mention in comment.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie here: https://jsfiddle.net/93a5aok3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are connecting the submit handler inside a click handler. Separate those so that you only register the submit handler once.

e.g. something like:

```
function sendSingeleTestCase(){
    saveScriptToLocalStorage();
}

var frm = $('#scriptCodeForm');
var btn =  $('#runSingleTest');
frm.submit(function (ev){
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: btn.attr('formaction'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Test would run once.");
        }
    });
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Also note: As you are using jQuery, please convert your click handler to just this:

```
$('#runSingleTest').click(sendSingeleTestCase);
```

or place the handler code inside an anoymous function:

```
$('#runSingleTest').click(function(){
    saveScriptToLocalStorage();
    // Do other stuff
});
```

Comment: What about case, when I've few submit button in the same form?

Comment: They all trigger `submit`. You need to check which button triggered it. You can do that with `ev.target` inside the `submit` event.